Need a WordPress license manager plugin
I want a WordPress license manager plugin that has a C/C++ example teaching you how to activate/check serial number/key/activation code in the client app. The license manager should support license binding with client hardware. It would be better if the plugin supports WooCommerce(but okay if it does not support). Do you guys hear of such a plugin? I find some in WordPress plugin repository, but none has a C/C++ example so I don't know how to modify the client app to communicate with the license server. If there is no such WordPress plugin, can you please recommend other types of open source licensing system that's not too complex? Thanks.

Can you realistically do binding to hardware in these days of virtual machines, containers and servers-as-cattle etc.?

Why do you want C/C++? Is that for the hosting server or your management console? How are you planning to implement that, e.g. a custom PHP module?

@Rup I want C/C++ because the client app is written using C++ on PC. I think binding to hardware is not a problem because the app cannot be run in virtual machines.
